# ZF2 + Doctrine Entity - return query as array with datetime object?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to output some data retrieved from a querybuilder query into a Datatables table with AJAX. I have my Zend Framework 2 controller and action setup to return a new JsonModel, which works fine.

However, one of the fields in my Entity is a datetime field, so Doctrine automatically returns it as a Datetime object, which is causing problems parsing the JSON response for Datatables.  See sample JSON below:

`{"aaData":[{"rSerial":"345gsdf","rPin":"76","rValue":633,"rDatetime":{"date":"2013-12-18 09:24:19","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"}}],"success":true}`

Is there a way that I can return the rDatetime column formatted as a string at the point the results are retrieved, to save me having to loop through and change it's format in the array of results?

`$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually seems to be a [bug report for this issue](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-657) with a [supposed fix here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/ea14bcff4a2a78bf774e8847b6645dca112f9757)

So I assume you can use the [scalar hydration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#scalar-hydration)

> Returns a flat rectangular result set instead of an object graph you can use scalar hydration

So your query would just need

```
$query   = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```